# flat list to hierarchy

Tags: linq, hierarchical-data

I'm having the hardest time converting a list(Of Folder) into a hierarchy.

```
Public Class Folder

Public Property FolderID() As Integer
Public Property Name() As String
Public Property ParentFolderID() As Integer
Public Property Children() as IEnumerable(Of Folder)

End Class
```

I need to return List(Of Folder) with Children populated.

I build a List(Of Folder) from the data in the database.

{1, "Folder 1", Nothing}
{2, "Folder 2", 1}
{3, "Folder 3", 2}
{4, "Folder 4", 3}
{5, "Folder 5", Nothing}

I can't figure out how to recursively move the child folders into the Children property of their parent.

I would like to do this with LINQ.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Thank you for your answer, but not quite there. Based on your answer, I came up with this which almost works.

```
Dim list = (From folder in folderList Select New Folder() With {
    .FolderID = folder.FolderID, 
    .Name = folder.Name, 
    .ParentFolderID = folder.ParentFolderID, 
    .Children = (From child in folderList 
                 Where child.ParentFolderID = item.FolderID).ToList()}).ToList()

{1, "Root", Nothing}
{2, "Child", 1}
{3, "Grand Child", 2}
```

I get a list of all three folders:

```
Root
--Child
Child
--Grand Child
Grand Child
```

Should look like:

```
Root
--Child
----Grand Child
```

Answer (score 14):

It's easy if you use the `ToLookup` extension method.

C#:

```
var lookup = folderList.ToLookup(f => f.ParentFolderID);

foreach (var folder in folderList)
{
    folder.Children = lookup[folder.FolderID].ToList();
}

var rootFolders = lookup[null].ToList();
```

VB:

```
Dim lookup = folderList.ToLookup(Function (f) f.ParentFolderID)

For Each folder In folderList
    folder.Children = lookup(folder.FolderID).ToList()
Next

Dim rootFolders = lookup(Nothing).ToList()
```

Comment: A nice usage of the ToLookup extension.

Answer (score 0):

C# version

```
var newList = list.Select(o=> 
   new Fodler
   { 
        FodlerID = o.FodlerID,
        Children = list.Where(q => q.ParentId == o.FodlerID),
        Parent = list.FirstOrDefault(q => q.FodlerID == o.ParentID ),
        //Other properties goes here
   });
```

Although if you do the correct mapping in e.g. EF, it should be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsHierarchy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        Func<T, T> parentSelector, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>> childrenSelector, T root = default(T))
    {
        var items = collection.Where(x => parentSelector(x).Equals(root));
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var childrenProperty = (childrenSelector.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
            childrenProperty.SetValue(item, collection.AsHierarchy(parentSelector, childrenSelector, item), null);
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
list.AsHierarchy(x => x.Parent, x => x.Children);
```

Comment: Hi.This snippet seems very interresting for me, but how to invoke it?
I dont understand the x=>x.Parent? Can anyone give an example to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to create the above extension method in a static class to use it. The first parameter specifies how to find the parent node, and the second parameter how to get the children collection.