# How to deserialize only part of a large xml file to c# classes?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I've already read some posts and articles on how to deserialize xml but still haven't figured out the way I should write the code to match my needs, so.. I'm apologizing for another question about deserializing xml ))

I have a large (50 MB) xml file which I need to deserialize. I use xsd.exe to get xsd schema of the document and than autogenerate c# classes file which I put into my project. I want to get some (not all) data from this xml file and put it into my sql database.

Here is the hierarchy of the file (simplified, xsd is very large):

```
public class yml_catalog 
{
    public yml_catalogShop[] shop { /*realization*/ }
}

public class yml_catalogShop
{
    public yml_catalogShopOffersOffer[][] offers { /*realization*/ }
}

public class yml_catalogShopOffersOffer
{
    // here goes all the data (properties) I want to obtain ))
}
```

And here is my code:

**first approach:**

```
yml_catalogShopOffersOffer catalog;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(yml_catalogShopOffersOffer));
var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\div_kid.xml");
catalog = (yml_catalogShopOffersOffer) serializer.Deserialize(reader);//exception occures
reader.Close();
```

I get InvalidOperationException: There is an error in the XML(3,2) document

**second approach:**

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(yml_catalogShopOffersOffer));
yml_catalogShopOffersOffer result;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\div_kid.xml"))          
{
    result = (yml_catalogShopOffersOffer)ser.Deserialize(reader); // exception occures
}
```

InvalidOperationException: There is an error in the XML(0,0) document

**third:** I tried to deserialize the entire file:

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(yml_catalog)); // exception occures
 yml_catalog result;
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\div_kid.xml"))          
 {
     result = (yml_catalog)ser.Deserialize(reader);
 }
```

And I get the following:

```
error CS0030: The convertion of type "yml_catalogShopOffersOffer[]" into "yml_catalogShopOffersOffer" is not possible.

error CS0029: The implicit convertion of type "yml_catalogShopOffersOffer" into "yml_catalogShopOffersOffer[]" is not possible.
```

So, how to fix (or overwrite) the code to not get the exceptions?

**edits:**  Also when I write:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"C:\div_kid.xml");
```

The XmlException occures: unpermitted data on root level, string 1, position 1.

Here is the first string of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
```

**edits 2:**
The xml file short example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">
<yml_catalog date="2012-11-01 23:29">
<shop>
   <name>OZON.ru</name>
   <company>?????? "???????????????? ??????????????"</company>
   <url>http://www.ozon.ru/</url>
   <currencies>
     <currency id="RUR" rate="1" />
   </currencies>
   <categories>
      <category id=""1126233>base category</category>
      <category id="1127479" parentId="1126233">bla bla bla</category>
      // here goes all the categories
   </categories>
   <offers>
      <offer>
         <price></price>
         <picture></picture>
      </offer>
      // other offers
   </offers>
</shop>
</yml_catalog>
```

**P.S.**
I've already acccepted the answer (it's perfect). But now I need to find "base category" for each Offer using categoryId. The data is hierarchical and the base category is the category that has no "parentId" attribute. So, I wrote a recursive method to find the "base category", but it never finishes. Seems like the algorythm is not very fast))
Here is my code: (in the main() method)

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\div_kid.xml");
var offers = doc.Descendants("shop").Elements("offers").Elements("offer");
foreach (var offer in offers.Take(2))
        {
            var category = GetCategory(categoryId, doc);
            // here goes other code
        }
```

Helper method:

```
public static string GetCategory(int categoryId, XDocument document)
    {
        var tempId = categoryId;
            var categories = document.Descendants("shop").Elements("categories").Elements("category");
            foreach (var category in categories)
            {
                if (category.Attribute("id").ToString() == categoryId.ToString())
                {
                    if (category.Attributes().Count() == 1)
                    {
                        return category.ToString();
                    }
                    tempId = Convert.ToInt32(category.Attribute("parentId"));
                }
            }
        return GetCategory(tempId, document);
    }
```

Can I use recursion in such situation? If not, how else can I find the "base category"?

Comment: Could you give a small sample of what the XML schema looks like by showing us some example data and how you'd expect your objects to get from it? (p.s., you need to `Load()` a file, not `Parse()` it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give LINQ to XML a try. `XElement result = XElement.Load(@"C:\div_kid.xml");`

Querying in LINQ is brilliant but admittedly a little weird at the start. You select nodes from the Document in a SQL like syntax, or using lambda expressions. Then create anonymous objects (or use existing classes) containing the data you are interested in.

Best is to see it in action.

- [miscellaneous examples of LINQ to XML](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/LINQ-to-XML-Miscellaneous-9e881847/sourcecode?fileId=23920&pathId=2055777278)
- [simple sample using xquery and lambdas](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/LINQ-LINQ-to-XML-using-6f2d2218/sourcecode?fileId=24066&pathId=912880959)
- [sample denoting namespaces](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/LINQ-to-XML-XName-Samples-6ce5f9c3)
- There is tons more on msdn. Search for LINQ to XML.

Based on your sample XML and code, here's a specific example:

```
var element = XElement.Load(@"C:\div_kid.xml");
var shopsQuery =
    from shop in element.Descendants("shop")
    select new
    {
        Name = (string) shop.Descendants("name").FirstOrDefault(),
        Company = (string) shop.Descendants("company").FirstOrDefault(),
        Categories = 
            from category in shop.Descendants("category")
            select new {
                Id = category.Attribute("id").Value,
                Parent = category.Attribute("parentId").Value,
                Name = category.Value
            },
        Offers =
            from offer in shop.Descendants("offer")
            select new { 
                Price = (string) offer.Descendants("price").FirstOrDefault(),
                Picture = (string) offer.Descendants("picture").FirstOrDefault()
            }

    };

foreach (var shop in shopsQuery){
    Console.WriteLine(shop.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(shop.Company);
    foreach (var category in shop.Categories)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(category.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(category.Id);
    }
    foreach (var offer in shop.Offers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(offer.Price);
        Console.WriteLine(offer.Picture);
    }
}
```

As an extra: Here's how to deserialize the tree of categories from the flat `category` elements.
You need a proper class to house them, for the list of Children must have a type:

```
class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Descendants {
        get
        {
            return (from child in Children
                    select child.Descendants).SelectMany(x => x).
                    Concat(new Category[] { this });
        }
    }
}
```

To create a list containing all distinct categories in the document:

```
var categories = (from category in element.Descendants("category")
                    orderby int.Parse( category.Attribute("id").Value )
                    select new Category()
                    {
                        Id = int.Parse(category.Attribute("id").Value),
                        ParentId = category.Attribute("parentId") == null ?
                            null as int? : int.Parse(category.Attribute("parentId").Value),
                        Children = new List<Category>()
                    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Then organize them into a tree (Heavily borrowed from [flat list to hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694227/flat-list-to-hierarchy)):

```
var lookup = categories.ToLookup(cat => cat.ParentId);
foreach (var category in categories)
{
    category.Children = lookup[category.Id].ToList();
}
var rootCategories = lookup[null].ToList();
```

To find the root which contains `theCategory`:

```
var root = (from cat in rootCategories
            where cat.Descendants.Contains(theCategory)
            select cat).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: the loading works! Console.WriteLine(result.Name); displays "yml_catalog". But how can I get the data that is on the next levels?? Can You provide some code please?

Comment: I have added links to some samples. But the simplest answer to that is they are accessible through result.Descendants("elementname")

Comment: also I recommend to look through Linq to Xml C# code samples - there is all the information)

Comment: I've added a specific example based on the XML document you provided.

Comment: thanks for additional code, it works great! Can You look through the edits I made at the end of my question post? (I also need to find the "base category" using "categoryId" and I use recursion that never finishes to execute). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had to look around for that, and I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694227/flat-list-to-hierarchy . All parent categories must be mentioned in the xml document for this to work, though.