# Partial XML Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml

I need to deserialize such XML to my object but it is necessary to keep "Configuration" node as string, XmlElement, XElement or something else. Because i don't know the type of those configuration. And i'll need its string or some "generic" type to put into object that will be created by reflection. Those object knows the type of configuration and will deserialize it.

```
<EngineConfiguration>
    <AssemblyName>AssemblyName</AssemblyName>
    <ClassName>ClassName</ClassName>
    <Configuration key1="value" key2="value" key3="value"/>
</EngineConfiguration>
```

Type

```
[DataContract]
public class EngineConfiguration
{
    [DataMember]
    public object Configuration { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry im not understanding what you are trying to do. Can you try and explain further?

Comment: Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541158/how-to-deserialize-only-part-of-a-large-xml-file-to-c-sharp-classes#14541675) useful? LINQ does what I think you're asking.

Comment: @CathalMF, @John C Ideally i wanna have those type  
  [DataContract] `public class EngineConfiguration {     [DataMember]     public XElement Configuration { get; set; }     [DataMember]     public string AssemblyName { get; set; }     [DataMember]     public string ClassName { get; set; } }`   
But actually i have an exception on deserializing "There is an error in XML document (3, 14)." "The XmlReader must be on a node of type Element instead of a node of type Text."

Comment: Post the code you are using to deserialize.

Comment: @CathalMF
`public static T DeserializeFromXMLString<T>(this string xmlString)
{
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
}`